# Notification of RAID-Status in Windows 2008?

Tags: raid, notifications, windows-server-2008-r2

is there a way to configure Windows (2008 R2 SP1) to send an e-mail (or display a window/message) if one of the drives in a (software) RAID1 is having problems and needs to be replaced?

I'm looking for a solution for the built-in RAID support in Windows.

Comment: Unless it's software RAID or there's a utility made by the RAID controller, I don't think so.  If it's branded they might have a utility (e.g. Dell OpenManage).

Comment: yes, it is a software-raid (by windows itself, "mirrored drive")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never done this, but I have a feeling that there is a chance that you can find some way of getting there successfully.

I actually base my feeling on the [thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/5d3c3d5c-38ee-4a3d-9243-17712556eab8/) cited by Oliver Salzburg, which does say that an Event ID 26 (Informational) is generated in win7/2008 (probably with volmgr as source) when a fault-tolerant volume is no longer accessible.
It also remarks that Windows 8 adds the more informative new Event id 142 in addition to Event 26.

I think you should try to send yourself for starters all the events generated by volmgr, then filter-out the ones you don't want. However, I don't have a Server 2008 R2 to play with for that,
so cannot give precise instructions.

Below are some links that might help in associating an action with event(s) :

[Getting event log contents by email on an event log trigger](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2010/06/16/getting-event-log-contents-by-email-on-an-event-log-trigger.aspx)
[E-Mail notification when hard disk full](https://serverfault.com/questions/122422/e-mail-notification-when-hard-disk-full)
[Run a Task in Response to a Given Event](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748900.aspx)
[Using Event Description as criteria for a rule](http://blogs.technet.com/b/kevinholman/archive/2008/04/22/using-event-description-as-criteria-for-a-rule.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this article to create a log for software raid in your event log.

[How to make the Windows Software RAID log to the event log](http://www.eventlogblog.com/blog/2012/02/how-to-make-the-windows-softwa.html)

And then use the following article to create a schedule task that monitor event viewer and send the email when it finds that log.

[Attaching Tasks to Event Viewer Logs and Events](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Attaching-Tasks-Event-Viewer-Logs-Events.html)

or

[Getting event log contents by email on an event log trigger](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2010/06/16/getting-event-log-contents-by-email-on-an-event-log-trigger.aspx) (as VBwhatnow said)

I Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

This thread seems to provide further insight into the issue: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/5d3c3d5c-38ee-4a3d-9243-17712556eab8/

The gist of it seems to be that it's not available (at least in Windows 7, so I assume the same hold true for Server 2008 R2). But, according to a Microsoft engineer in that thread, it'll be available in the next generation of Windows operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script that sends and email when a failure is detected in the windows event log.

Using the windows task scheduler would be one way you could do this.

Try adapting this solution the someone made for sending an email on an event log condition
http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2010/06/16/getting-event-log-contents-by-email-on-an-event-log-trigger.aspx

You probably do not have any past RAID failures in your event log to base the task script on so you'll need to look up how windows reports these errors and manually create the condition.

You could send an email on any critical error that contains the word RAID.